# wxwidget 3.1.2 codeblocks 17.04 error at linking step

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

OS : windows 10 64 bit
IDE : codeblocks 17.12
Compiler : gcc 7.3
with
wxWidget 3.1.2

i build wxWidget 3.1.2 according to the official guide without changing any defaults

make -f makefile.gcc  (make v4.2)

i am using codeblocks wxwidget start script 3.1.X

i have choosen correct option according to the wxWidget build
(Monolithic unicode and debug)

The codeblock generated sample problem is not linking properly

( gives build fail with 0 error 0 warning )

```
-------------- Clean: Debug in sac (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Cleaned "sac - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in sac (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -c C:\Users\MC\Desktop\wxw\sac\wx_pch.h -o wx_pch.h.gch\Debug_wx_pch_h_gch
g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -c C:\Users\MC\Desktop\wxw\sac\GUIFrame.cpp -o obj\Debug\GUIFrame.o
windres.exe -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\lib\gcc_dll\mswu  -J rc -O coff -i C:\Users\MC\Desktop\wxw\sac\resource.rc -o obj\Debug\resource.res
g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -c C:\Users\MC\Desktop\wxw\sac\sacApp.cpp -o obj\Debug\sacApp.o
g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DWXUSINGDLL -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Winvalid-pch -include wx_pch.h -DWX_PRECOMP -Wall -g -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -c C:\Users\MC\Desktop\wxw\sac\sacMain.cpp -o obj\Debug\sacMain.o
g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-3.1.2\lib\gcc_dll -o bin\Debug\sac.exe obj\Debug\GUIFrame.o obj\Debug\sacApp.o obj\Debug\sacMain.o  obj\Debug\resource.res -mthreads  -lwxmsw31u -mwindows
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))

Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 12 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 12 second(s))
```

any help ?

Comment: What is the error? Have you tried from the commandline? What is the code in question? There's not enough info and the info provided is possibly not relevant. As a new user, make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Codeblocks will use MinGW to provide the g++ compiler. Edit your environment variables and add the path to MinGW\bin folder (which will vary depending on whether you installed Codeblocks with TDM MinGW or the stand-alone MinGW/Msys. Then you can open a Command Prompt and simply paste each from your compilation attempt above and determine where the error occurs. Nothing stands out from what you posted as being inherently wrong.

Comment: @SachinShet, by default wxWidgets will not build monolithic library. Re-create your project without monolithic option.

Comment: The compiler used for building the wxwidget and the compiler in codeblocks settings are same. which is gcc 7.3. In the command line i can build the sample projects given under wxwidget folder.. thanks @DavidC.Rankin  .. i will try re-building with monolithic=0 thanks

Comment: @SachinShet, what I meant is for you to create a C::B project with `MONOLITHIC` option unchecked. Also, not sure if the `DEBUG` is set to `ON` by default. Please rebuild the wxWidgets with explicitly specifying `DEBUG` option and re-create the C::B project with appropriate options (one matching the wxWidgets build). Also, what error is spit during compilation? If you try to run the last command from the command prompt and not build from the IDE what happens?

Answer (score 0):

This post assumes you have compiled `wxWidgets 3.1.3` and are successful in compiling the executable samples via make and *makefile.gcc* that is included and are using *gcc*.

It also assumes you have already applied your environment vars in windows, applied your compiler flags `wx-config --cxxflags` and linker flag `wx-config --libs`.

It seems everyone else has dugout the makefile library order and has fixed it inside of codeblocks. I wanted to build small all in one apps so I decided on a *MONOLITHIC* with `SHARED=0 UNICODE` build.

It seems the easiest fix is thus.

CodeBlocks arranges the linker library order in a different order than the makefile does and jams up the linker, in my case varying from "theme" something or other to scrollbar issues.

So the quickest work around I've found is to delete all the entries in the codeblocks build options lists and enter only into the "Other Linker Options" for Debug and Release and this does work.

So from the console listing the makefile shows copy those linker settings in the order that makefile settings list. So until someone makes a header fixup entry for something higher than 2.8.8 there is this cumbersome workaround.

In my case the working order is as follows:

```
-mwindows
-lwxmsw31ud
-lwxmsw31ud_gl
-lwxscintillad
-lwxtiffd
-lwxjpegd
-lwxpngd
-lwxzlibd
-lwxregexud
-lwxexpatd
-lkernel32
-luser32
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-lwinspool
-lwinmm
-lshell32
-lshlwapi
-lcomctl32
-lole32
-loleaut32
-luuid
-lrpcrt4
-ladvapi32
-lversion
-lwsock32
-lwininet
-loleacc
-luxtheme
```

In Release it is the same less the "d" which designates the debug file i.e.:
`-lwxmsw31u_gl` instead of `-lwxmsw31ud_gl`,
`-lwxtiff`      in place of `-lwxtiffd` etc...